# Array.Sort() trying to implement IComparable for sorting

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to follow some example in learning sorting arrays. Example use Id as integer to sort by this property, since my object use Guid datatype instead of int I'm decided to use Created DateTime property to sort array. Here's the code

```
Car.cs
    public class Car:ICar,IComparable
    {
       ... properties
       int IComparable.CompareTo(object)
       {
          Car temp = obj as Car;
          if (temp != null)
          {
             if (this.Created > temp.Created)
                return 1;
             if (this.Created < temp.Created)
                return -1;
            else 
                return 0;
          }
          else {throw new ArgumentException("Parameter is not a Car object");}
       }
    }
```

Garage.cs

```
public class Garage : IEnumerable
    {
        private Car[] cars = new Car[4];

        public Garage()
        {
            cars[0] = new Car() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Corolla", Created = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3), CurrentSpeed = 90 };
            cars[1] = new Car() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Mazda", Created = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2), CurrentSpeed = 80 };
        }
       ...
}
```

Program.cs

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Garage cars = new Garage();
           Console.WriteLine("sorting array:");
           Array.Sort(cars); // error occured
        }
```

**Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Car' to 'System.Array'**

Comment: Um, your last two lines appear not to be in a method. Could you please give your *actual* code which is causing a problem?

Comment: Also you cannot have private inside methods, agree with Jon, need to see your actual code

Comment: Also, your cars array has two null's at the end of the array.

Comment: @Jon Skeet here is my actual code.

Comment: Is the message really 'from Car to Array'? It would seem it can't convert the `Garage` to an `Array`, as the `Array.Sort` requires an array, which the Garage object is not according to this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes you want to sort the array in place, and not create a new one.

To your `Garage` class, add a method (so you don't have to expose the inner array):

```
public void Sort() {
    Array.Sort(cars);
}
```

Then call this method from your program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Garage garage = new Garage();
    garage.Sort();
    //It should be sorted now if you enumerate over it!
}
```

I've taken the liberty of calling your `Garage` object `garage` rather than `cars` which can be confusing.

I haven't tested this, but it's so straightforward, that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `private Car[] cars` is defined within a block (between curly braces) and you reference it outside of that block when you write `Array.Sort(cars)`.

So somewhere you define a variable `cars` that is of the wrong type.

If you do the `Array.Sort` in the same block where you define the array, it will work.

Comment: @Roy the variable `cars` is actually of type `Garage` if you read the code, so that is not true. Performing it on the `cars` field of the `Garage` object would indeed not be possible, beacse it is private. That would be the way to go if they wanted to use Array.Sort though.

Comment: @RenéWolferink: the code examples above have changed since my answer.